# Href link not being clicked by Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to select and click on the link in href from the below HTML snippet using Selenium Webdriver Chrome. But I am getting an NoSuchElement Exception

```html
<a href="http://www.legislation.vic.gov.au/Domino\Web_Notes\LDMS\PubStatbook.nsf?opendatabase" alt="Victorian Statute Book" onmouseover="document.images[&quot;StatBook&quot;].src=&quot;/domino/web_notes/LDMS/pubhome.nsf/goldRightImage.gif&quot;" onmouseout="document.images[&quot;StatBook&quot;].src=&quot;/domino/web_notes/LDMS/pubhome.nsf/goldLeftImage.gif&quot;" onclick="top.frames['TopWeb2'].document.getElementById('CurrentDB').innerHTML='Currently&nbsp;in&nbsp;Statute&nbsp;Book'"><img src="/domino/web_notes/LDMS/pubhome.nsf/goldLeftImage.gif" name="StatBook" alt="" border="0" onclick="top.frames['TopWeb2'].document.getElementById('CurrentDB').innerHTML='Currently&nbsp;in&nbsp;Statute&nbsp;Book'">
<img src="/domino/web_notes/LDMS/pubhome.nsf/VicStat_title.gif" alt="Statute Book" border="0"></a>
```

This is my Python code:

```
   import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import csv
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {
    'download.default_directory':
    r'D:\LEG_DOWNLOAD\CTH NEW'
}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\CHROME\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
browser.get('http://www.legislation.vic.gov.au/')

with open(r"D:\LEG_DOWNLOAD\VIC.csv") as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # Skip the heading line
    readCSV.__next__()

    for row in readCSV:
        acts = row[0:616]
        element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='http://www.legislation.vic.gov.au/Domino\Web_Notes\LDMS\PubStatbook.nsf?opendatabase']")
        element.click()
        time.sleep(2)
browser.back()
time.sleep(2)
browser.quit()
```

I am getting the below exception

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='http://www.legislation.vic.gov.au/Domino\Web_Notes\LDMS\PubStatbook.nsf?opendatabase']"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.137 (86ee722808adfe9e3c92e6e8ea746ade08423c7e),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Could you please advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Chrome version and selenium chrome driver version must be same.
http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Does the page have time to load? May be webdriver cannot locate element because it's not loaded yet.

Comment: Tried that too using webdriver wait but does not do anything

Comment: I saw the site. So your problem is frames. You should first of all switch webdriver to frame you want to work with, and than start to search elements on this frame via webdriver.

Comment: Cool that should be it. Will give it a try